# UIBarButtonItem not shown in View

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, swift2

I'm trying to add two items to my navigation controller in a view. Before I always used to select the view and than click product -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller.

I noticed this suddenly wasn't working anymore in xCode 7.1. I updated Xcode to version 7.2 and was hoping this would solve my problem, but it didn't.

I tried to add the UIBarButtonItems using code, but this is also not working. But, when I change the color of the navigation controller, I can see the result of the color.

This is the code that I tried to add the items to my navigation bar:

```
    let left = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "hammer"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "expandButtonPressed")
    let right = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "buildButtonPressed")

    navigationController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = right
    navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = left
```

The methods **expandButtonPressed** and **buildButtonPressed** have been added to my view controller.

Below are several screenshots explaining what controls I have in my view, and how the different view are setup.

[image: Screenshot displaying controls in view]
[image: Screenshot displaying the setup of my view controllers in the story board.]

Here is a screenshot running the app: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_FbD3kpEuvXYS1QYks0YTBVNmc

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: What do you see in runtime?

Comment: @MarcosCrispino an empty navigation bar

Comment: remove navigationcontroller from first viewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd comment this if I could; but that Navigation Controller *before* the Tab Bar Controller in the Storyboard seems a bit funky.

I seem to remember some Apple Documentation saying that a Tab Bar should be the root view. I can't see it right now, but I'll keep looking.

Comment: Yep, for sure a UITabBarController should be the root, with UINavigationController's as each of the child view controller's.

Answer (score 4):

A `navigationItem` represents how a UIViewController wants its navigation bar to look like within a `UINavigationController`.

With `navigationController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = right`, you're modifying the navigationItem of the navigationController itself.

What you want, is to simply change the navigationItem for the UIViewController, so remove the `navigationController?.` part of your statement:

`navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = right`

All UIViewController's have navigationItems, which is why a UINavigationController itself has one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put each child ViewControllers inside a UINavigationBarController. Something like this:

[image]